# Visual Studio 2017 is building project over and over again

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a big solution (~ 450 projects), where some projects are building over and over again, although I haven't changed anything.

When I change build output verbosity to `diagnostic` it says:

> Project 'ProjectA' is not up to date. Missing input file 'C:\Src\Project.Core\Bin\Release\ProjectB.dll'

`ProjectA` dependes on `ProjectB` and I'm building configuration `Debug`, so why is Visual Studio checking for the file `ProjectB.dll` in the `Release`-folder? `ProjectB.dll` gets built and copied in the correct folder (debug)!

The output path is the same for every project (c# and c++):

```
<OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)Bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
```

This is just an example. Multiple projects in my solution have this weird behavior. Seems like the c++ projects are causing this, but I have no clear evidence.

Here are my Process Monitor analysis of the file accesses:

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**

ProjectA (C# project) references ProjectB (C++ project) using a `ProjectReference`:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\ProjectB.vcxproj">
   <Project>{F2F4C146-8A98-432B-BB9F-A06C4B4162CF}</Project> 
   <Name>ProjectB</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

There's this setting for .NET Core projects:

[image]

Is there something similar for projects targeting .NET Framework?

**UPDATE 3:**

Seems like the code for the `FastUpToDateCheck` for C#-projects is in the `csproj.dll` assembly. Since it's a native assembly, I can't look into the code. That's a pity.

Comment: How did you set up your dependencies?

Comment: It could be that you add reference for `ProjectB` in `ProjectA` from `ProjectB`'s `Release` folder, as your all projects are in the same solution make sure that you add reference from solution.

Comment: ProjectA references ProjectB via `ProjectReference`

Comment: That is strange. Usually project output will be inside it's folder in path `bin\$(Configuration)` but from screenshot it appears that you change output for all projects to be in a single solution folder. Can you double check project `ProjectB` properties in `Build` tab that both `Configuration` Release and Debug output configured to a correct directory.

Comment: @Ebraheem Both output directories (debug and release) are set to `$(SolutionDir)Bin\$(Configuration)\`` for every project, including `ProjectB`. `ProjectB` gets built before `ProjectA` and it gets copied to the correct folder (debug), so the path should be correct.

Comment: It seems that there are other projects in your solution that have any changes to projectB, you can try to create a new projectC, then add reference to the projectA, to check if still have this issue? If not, you may need to check which project in the solution change the output of projectB.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I don't think that any project is changing the output of projectB. The problem is, that Visual Studio, when building projectA, is looking for projectB in the wrong directory. When I'm building configuration `debug` Visual Studio must not look in the directory `release`.

Comment: I added a second update to my question

Comment: Is your _solution's_ debug configuration set to build ProjectB's _project_ debug configuration? This has tripped me up several times with more complex solutions. Check under `Build -> Configuration Manager...`.

Comment: @pandorafalters Yes, otherwise the output of `projectB` would be in the `release` folder, which is not the case. Visual Studio is just wrongly searching in the `release` folder for `projectB.dll` when doing `FastUpToDateCheck` for `projectA`

Comment: I still can’t reproduce this error at my side with such complex situation. And if this issue persists after you create a new solution with a C# and C++ project in it (use PropertyReference in csproj to specify the vcxproj)? If it persists, please share us the simple sample so that we can check it directly. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not all of your projects are in the solution file (*.sln).
Given that you are using project references. i.e. `<ProjectReference`

When some of the projects are in the solution file (*.sln), and they reference another project outside of the solution file, MSBuild will build the other project, but not with the configuration you are building. It always or usually (a bug) will build using the opposite configuration you are using.

Super Duper annoying bug btw.

As a work-around you could just declare an ItemGroup with all your projects, and just pass that straight to MSBuild and not use a solution at all.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Files Include="**\*.csproj" />
   <Files Include="**\*.vcxproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Build">
   <MSBuild Projects="@(Files)" Properties="Configuration=Debug" />
</Target>
```

If they all use `<ProjectReference`, then MSBuild will automatically determine the order that they get built in.

Or you could just create a solution that has everything in it.

Comment: caveat about massive solution files: They take forever to load into visual studio. But they work fine on the command line when passed to msbuild.exe

Comment: That's not the case. Every project i'm referencing is in the solution. Maybe I have explained it not good enough, but every project is built in the correct configuration and gets copied into the right directory. The problem is, that Visual Studio is looking for projectB.dll in the wrong directory (for example the release folder), when it's doing the FastUpToDateCheck for projectA. And because for obvious reasons the file is not available there it's building projectA over and over again although they haven't been any changes..

Comment: You should output a verbose log and save it to file, so other's can see what is going on.

Comment: Visual Studios FastUpToDateCheck isn't logging anything. I just can provide the capture of the ProcessMonitor, which I posted in my question.

Comment: msbuild <projectfile> -t:Build -p:Configuration=Debug -v:m -fl -flp:Verbosity=Normal,Logfile=build.log

Comment: We build the big solution only in Visual Studio - locally and on our build servers. Unfortunately your msbuild command won't help us, because the problem clearly lays in Visual Studios "FastUpToDateCheck". This check is made before even calling msbuild to save time.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same Issue as you.  I do not have a fix - just a workaround which works with msbuild  15 and up.  Same as you I found no way to pass the correct target output path from the clr project to the csproj `ProjectReference` element or any of its targets.

Add the following code somewhere in the `Directory.Build.targets` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2017)) for your solution and the update checks will work.

All that happens is that the dll will be copied from the `OutputPath` to the `IntermediateOutputPath` which allows the FastUpToDateCheck to find it.

I have found no issues with doing it this way even though I consider it "hacky".  It might cause issues if you have very "non standard"  build paths / configuration

```
  <Target Name="CopyClrToProjectOutputForFastUpToDateCheck" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(CLRSupport)' == 'true' And '$(Language)' == 'C++'">
    <Message Text="Copying CLR Project output to intermeidate output path so that csprojs have the change to do fastuptodatecheck  $(OutputPath)$(TargetFileName) to $(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName)"/>
    <Copy SourceFiles=" $(OutputPath)$(TargetFileName)"               DestinationFiles="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName)" />
  </Target>
```